# Delay url link showing in left corner

Tags: javascript, css, url, hyperlink

Is there a way to delay the url link showing in the bottom left corner of the browser via Javascript? I realize that a possible solution would be to add and remove the href attribute from the link on mouseover and set the delay using setTimeout. However, I don't believe that is an ideal solution due to google indexing, etc. and the links not having initial href attributes until mouseover. Also, changing the settings in the browser wouldn't be an option.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: No... AFAIK thats a browser object and so not selectable in that fashion.

Comment: Well you could try and manipulate `window.status` accordingly - but users can disable this in their browsers. That’s a setting btw. that was added specifically to _prevent_ web developers from not letting people see where a link points to immediately. What reason do you have for this anyway? I can not think of any legitimate use case for what you want here that would actually make any sense for me from the user perspective …

Comment: @04FS Thanks for the reply. People above my pay grade requested the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Put the href normally so it doesn't affect Google indexing. On hover, move the url to an alternate attribute and manage with onClick. When you want to show it, move the url back to the href.

I think you'll need to remove the href attribute all together because even an empty href will show something down there. If that's the case, your link without an href will need some css to fake the link visual. Ex : color:blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer